# How to print to different logs with different attributes by boost::log?

Tags: c++, logging, boost

For example, my log message has 4 levels(or attributes):

```
"error","warning","exception","action".
```

I want to print message whose attribute is "error" or "exception" to `fatal.log`, and print message whose attribute is "action" and "warning" to `regular.log`.
By searching online:

```
boost::shared_ptr<sinks::text_multifile_backend> backend = boost::make_shared< sinks::text_multifile_backend >();
backend->set_file_name_composer
(
    sinks::file::as_file_name_composer(boost::log::expressions::stream <<  boost::log::expressions::attr< std::string >("level") << ".log")
);

typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_multifile_backend > sink_t;
boost::shared_ptr< sink_t > sink(new sink_t(backend));

// Set the formatter
sink->set_formatter
    (
    boost::log::expressions::stream
    << boost::log::expressions::attr< std::string >("level")
    << boost::log::expressions::smessage
    );
```

It seems I can generate different log files by the level(attribute) and use

```
BOOST_LOG_SEV(_logger, level) << message;
```

to print different message to different logs. But it seems this will generate 4 logs, not just 2 logs because I have 4 level(attributes). How to print message with attributes into one log and message with other attributes into another log ?

Comment: you probably could solve this by setting up filters on your file sinks, one would filter attributes equal to  "error" or "exception" and the other "action" and "warning"

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing some code from [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/advanced_filtering.html), you probably could get away with this approach:

```
    using text_sink = sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_ostream_backend >;
    boost::shared_ptr< text_sink > sink = boost::make_shared< text_sink >();

    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
        boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("regular.log"));

    // set your 1st formatter

    sink->set_filter(expr::has_attr(tag_attr) && (tag_attr == "action" || tag_attr == "warning"));

    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

    sink = boost::make_shared< text_sink >();

    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
        boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("fatal.log"));

    // set your 2nd formatter

    sink->set_filter(expr::has_attr(tag_attr) && (tag_attr == "error" || tag_attr == "exception"));

    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
```

Comment: It shows no suitable user defined conversion from boost::make_shared< std::ofstream > to  const boost::make_shared< std::basic_stream<char,std::char_traits<char  >". By the way , if I want to generate filename based on date, may I use sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
        boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("Regular_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.log""));?

Comment: could you please specify at what line does it fail? As for the other question I would suggest reading documentation

Comment: It fails at  sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
        boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("regular.log"));

Comment: I keep searching for the header file for logging::core, but I cannot find it. VS2013 keeps saying it cannot find logging::core. Can you tell me that please?

Comment: I already tried this header file, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: do you have both #include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
and
#include <boost/log/core.hpp> ?

Comment: Still doesn't work even though I add #include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129661/discussion-between-oleg-bogdanov-and-firstaccount).